# Background Grey

Tags: html, css

In some browsers, my website http://haptotherapiemris.nl, the background appears with grey blocks.

This is my background css code:

```
.main {
margin: 0 auto;
background: transparent url(http://dansolution.nl/klanten/background/bg.jpg) repeat-y                center top;
width: 1000px;
min-height: 1000px;
text-align: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

check your body style:

```
body {
background-color: #595959;   /*  here is the color  */
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
width: 100%;
color: #595959;
font: normal 13px/1.8em Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
text-align: center;
letter-spacing: 0.06em;
}
```

in `style.css` line 2. you need to delete `background-color` from body style.

Answer (score 1):

Okay. What's your question?

Browsers will use their own default background color if you do not specify one. In your case, you've specified a background color of "transparent" for div.main, which does exactly what you'd expect--it is colorless, showing the element behind div.main. The element behind div.main is body, which has a background-color:#595959. This is why your page background is grey.

Sources:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp